# Defining collision response in an Entity system

Tags: entity-system, collision-resolution

I'm building a really simple top-down 2d shooter which uses an Entity Component pattern.

I've added several different entities to a level and given them different collision groups. I have an entity to represent a teleporter (assigned to collision group A), a player entity (group B), and a bunch of enemies (Group C).

I understand that the actual collision response should be decided in the collision System based on the groups that the colliding entities belong to. What I can't figure out is how to define the specifics of a collision.

For example, if a player collides with a teleporter I need to move the player across the level. Where do I store the target location? I'd assume in a component on the teleporter. Should I create a whole new component just for that data? I feel it should be stored in the teleporters collision component but no all entities that use the collision component will require this data.

Could someone please try to enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have your answer :) I'd add a new component just to store that data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entity is just going to be a thing. It's an empty thing. The components you would add are its location, it's collision area, and a script saying where to move the collider if the collision area is hit. So you are definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking is correct, the target location should be stored within a separate component attached to a Teleporter entity. This does two things:

Attaching a TeleporterComponent to an entity effectively makes the entity a teleporter. You could now conceivably make any game object act as a teleporter just by attaching the TeleporterComponent. This is a major strength of ECS.

As evorlor mentioned, you are now able to write a short script/system that fires when a teleporter collides and handles the logic for teleporting the collider. This way, all the other collision response logic does not have to be concerned with target locations.